# PHP Random generator from array issues

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have done some research and fixed most of the issues but I can't find out why this is giving me a `Notice: Undefined index: in Line 344`
If you guys have any suggestion it would be greatly appreciated :D

Here is my Array:

```
$quote = array(

  1 => array(
    "quote" => 'The early bird gets the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese...',

    "name" => 'Stephen Wright'

    ),
  2 => array(
    "quote" => 'Your time is limited, so dont waste it living someone elses life.',

    "name" => 'Steve Jobs'

    ),
  3 => array(
    "quote" => 'When one door closes, another one opens. Or you could jut re-open the closed door. Because thats how doors work.',

    "name" => "Anon."

    ),
  4 => array(
    "quote" => "The two most important days in your life are the day you are born and the day you find out why.",

    "name" => "Mark Twain"

    ),
  5 => array(
    "quote" => "Before you criticize someone, you should walk a mile in their shoes, that way when you criticize them, you're a mile away and you have their shoes.",

    "name" => "Anon."
    ),
  );
  $random=array_rand($quote,1);
```

And my output:
[This is line 344]

```
<?php
    echo $quote[$random[0]]
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only get 1 array key with `array_rand()`, then you don't get an array back, just the key. As you can see in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

> When picking **only one entry**, array_rand() returns the **key** for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned. [...]

So after this you try to access the number as an array which doesn't work. So just remove the index from it, e.g.

```
echo $quote[$random]
                 //^ See here removed
```

Since it is a two dimension array you also have to sepcify the second dimesion if you want to use `echo` to print the value, e.g.

```
echo $quote[$random]["quote"];
echo $quote[$random]["name"];
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in; on line 344 Array

Comment: @Shaun'Prawn185Moore If you want to access the `quote` index use `quote` otherwise `name`, e.g. `echo $quote[$random]["name"]`. Or do: `print_r($quote[$random]);`

Comment: I put that in Rizier and got this again Notice: Undefined index: in 344

Comment: And I want it so when it echos it outputs both

Comment: @Shaun'Prawn185Moore Are you sure you didn't changed your array anywhere? [Code works fine!](http://3v4l.org/sJuSI)

Comment: But what do I put instead of print_r

Comment: @Shaun'Prawn185Moore `echo $quote[$random]["name"]; echo $quote[$random]["quote"]` ?!

Comment: <3 put that as an answer and i'll accept :D Thank you <3

Comment: @Shaun'Prawn185Moore You're welcome. (answer updated)